# How to print fields values from a data structure with MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, cpu-registers

The aim of the MASM program below declares a simple struct called Date. I initialize its fields (Day, Month, Year) respectively as (09, 01, 1980). I just want to print the value of the Day field.

Here's the MASM code :

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

include                         \masm32\include\windows.inc
include                         \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include                         \masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib                      \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib                      \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
include                         \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
includelib                      \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib

Date struct
    Day     DWORD               ?
    Month   DWORD               ?
    Year    DWORD               ?
Date ends

.data

PrintString                     BYTE                        "%s", 0

Monday                          Date                        <09, 1, 1980>

.data?

Pointer                         DWORD                       ?

.code

start:

    mov     ebx,                OFFSET Monday
    mov     ecx,                [ebx].Date.Day

    invoke  crt_printf,         PrintString,
                                [ebx].Date.Day

    ;invoke crt_printf,         PrintString,
    ;                           ecx

_quit:
    invoke  ExitProcess,        0

end start
```

The two 'crt_printf' invokes failed. Without them the program finishes successfully. A the execution a message box with the message "myExe.exe has stopped working". I think I have a "Segmentation fault" problem. So I don't understand why my register is empty or maybe it's not the right register to store this kind of data or maybe my approach is not good one.

Does anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.Day` is a `DWORD` (i.e. an integer), so you should use `%d` or `%u` rather than `%s` to print it.

Also, the invocation should be:

```
invoke  crt_printf,         ADDR PrintString,
                            [ebx].Date.Day
```

in order to pass the address of `PrintString` as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but even if I use %d or %u it's the same thing. The solution is to use print str$(ecx). It works !

Comment: That may work as well, but using `crt_printf` does work with the changes I listed. I confirmed it on my system.